# AdvancedDataGrid Width more than the Parent Container?

Tags: advanceddatagrid

Here is the hierarchy of my controls:

```
<Canvas  width="100%" height="100%">
  <ViewStack  width="100%" height="100%">
     <box id="box1" width="100%" height="100%">
       <AdvancedDataGrid width="100%" height="100%"/>
     </box>
     <box id="box2" width="100%" height="100%">
       <SomeOtherControl width="100%" height="100%"/>
     </box>
</ViewStack>
</Canvas>
```

My ADG is having around 30 - 40 columns and i am seeing two horizontal scroll bars, 1 is coming from ADG which is ok but another one is coming from parent container, so it seems ADG's width is getting assigned more than the parent container.

I can't set the width of ADG to explicit value because it is causing problems in scaling.

Please advise/Help.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting width="100%" on your ADG, set it to width="{box1.width}"